# Slack Incoming Webhook Attach Thread to own sent Message

Tags: slack, webrequest, payload

Fetching after posting a message to post a message to that message seems kind of repetitive and like bloated code.
So to send a slack message into a thread you need the thread_ts key/value, and to get this, as far as I know, you have to send a GET request to the API. But what if you want to start a thread in your own sent Message, is there an easier way?

currently:
`sendMsg payload{"text":"msg"} -> fetch Msg threadnumber -> send ThreadMsg {"text":"msg","thread_ts":"threadnumber"}`

What i would like is something along those lines:
`sendMsg payload{"text":"msg", "thread_message":"threaded msg"}`